# Find the lexicographically smallest sequence achievable

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, lexicographic

Here's the problem statement

```
Given a sequence of n integers arr, determine the lexicographically smallest sequence which may be obtained from it after performing at most k element swaps, each involving a pair of consecutive elements in the sequence.
Note: A list x is lexicographically smaller than a different equal-length list y if and only if, for the earliest index at which the two lists differ, x's element at that index is smaller than y's element at that index.
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around the what the phrase "lexicographically smaller" implies based on the above note. As I understand the English meaning of it, we are basically talking about a dictionary order. Let me explain my question with an example.

Here an example

```
Example 1
n = 3
k = 2
arr = [5, 3, 1]
output = [1, 5, 3]
We can swap the 2nd and 3rd elements, followed by the 1st and 2nd elements, to end up with the sequence [1, 5, 3]. This is the lexicographically smallest sequence achievable after at most 2 swaps.
```

The above example came with the problem statement. But wouldn't the lexicographically smallest sequence instead be [1, 3 , 5] instead of the provided answer (output) [1, 4, 3]?

Here's another

```
Example 2
n = 5
k = 3
arr = [8, 9, 11, 2, 1]
output = [2, 8, 9, 11, 1]
We can swap [11, 2], followed by [9, 2], then [8, 2].
```

Again, the answer I can see in this case is [1, 2, 8, 11, 9] (after three swaps), which is the smallest lexicographic ally and the provided answer is output = [2, 8, 9, 11, 1].

Am I reading the the problem statement incorrectly?

Comment: how can you move the 1 from the 5th position to the first with only 3 swaps (in the second example), and swap the 3 and 5 when you have already used all the swaps to bring 1 to the first position (in the first example)?

Comment: @Berto99 I'm guess that swapping 1 (index 4) with 8 (index 0) is permitted. So this would count as one operation.

Comment: from the assignment: `at most k element swaps, each involving a pair of consecutive elements in the sequence`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem statement says that we are allowed to make at most k swaps of consecutive elements in the process to get a lexicographically smallest sequence. The following explanation can help us understand it better. [**NOTE: keep in mind that you can only swap consecutive elements**]

1. n = 3
   k = 2 
   arr = [5, 3, 1]
   output = [1, 5, 3]
   **Approach:**
   **swap 1:** swap 3 and 1 (3<->1) ====> [5,1,3]
   **swap 2:** swap 5 and 1 (5<->1) ====> [1,5,3] #RESULT
2. n = 5
   k = 3
   arr = [8, 9, 11, 2, 1]
   output = [2, 8, 9, 11, 1]
   **Approach:**
   **swap 1:** swap 11 and 2 (11<->2) ===> [8, 9, 2, 11, 1]
   **swap 2:** swap 9 and 2 (9<->2) ===> [8, 2, 9, 11, 1]
   **swap 2:** swap 8 and 2 (9<->2) ===> [2, 8, 9, 11, 1] #RESULT

So, you can never get  [1, 2, 8, 11, 9] with 3 swaps of consecutive elements. 2 is the smallest element that you can move to the first index with at most 3 swaps of consecutive elements, but yes if k=4 then we can bring 1 to the first position.

So, the thing that you are missing is that the rule is you are allowed to swap at most k elements but the elements those you swap should be consecutive to each other.